# What is the Guardian of Forever?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

It was created, but yet it states that it's neither alive, nor machine. My guess is that it's not alive in the traditional sense, but "alive" in the way that Data or the EMH is alive.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_City_on_the_Edge_of_Forever_(episode)

Does anything in Star Trek speak further to this enigmatic being/object?

Comment: You already know this, but there are articles on [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_of_Forever) and [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_of_Forever) that might have useful information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Sentient, but constructed

According to the database entry concerning the Guardian of Forever at the [official Star Trek web site](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/guardian-of-forever#sthash.aePV7ivt.dpuf):

> Little is known about the Guardian of Forever. The Guardian served as a conduit for a race which traveled to a new age, thus leaving the planet – loosely referred to as the "Time Planet" – with the Guardian as its only ***indigenous, sentient resident***. The Guardian is more than ten million years old. Its function seems to be that of showing the past of any planet, with the exception of the Time Planet itself, and of allowing journeys in time.
>
> Not much is known about the civilization ***which built the Guardian***, other than impressive, extensive ruins and the Guardian of Forever itself. The materials and principles on which the Guardian of Forever are based upon are completely unknown.

From this, we can conclude that the Guardian was constructed for a specific purpose, and so perhaps not alive in the traditional sense, but the entry affirms that it is nonetheless sentient, and so the parallel you draw with Soongian androids and the EMH is apt.

**This is the extent of what is known in canon, as per the admission of the official web site itself.**

Comment: Perhaps the builders of the Guardian of Forever were the race who became the Q.

Comment: I was thinking it was built by the Ancients.

Comment: So, presumably, it would be possible for an advanced race to "kill" the Guardian.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : I would agree.

Comment: @Praxis *"The Guardian is more than ten million years old."* The Guardian is far older than ten million years. It says *"A question. Since before **your sun burned hot in space** and before your race was born, I have awaited a question."* Our sun is 4.5 billion years old, so the Guardian must be even older than that.

Comment: @RichS : I'm just quoting the official source.  It's possible it was a typo and that they meant ten billion.

Comment: @Praxis In that case, the source has a typo or whomever wrote the entry didn't know that quote from the real source. ;-)